# Find Correctly Answered Questions in an Online Test with Single and Multi Choice Questions

Tags: sql, oracle11g

See the tables : http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10356431/Shared/screen.png

Please help me to construct a SQL to find the correctly answered questions in an online test for a particular test_id.

I have constructed one.

```
SELECT COUNT(UNIQUE d.question_id) AS CORRECT
FROM test_response d,
     question_response r
WHERE d.response_id   = r.question_resp_id
AND r.correct_response_flag != 'N'
AND d.test_id = '10113'
```

But the problem is while it will find the single choice questions accurately, it won't if its a multi-choice as suppose out of 4 responses 2 are correct, choosing one will count it as a correctly answered question which is inaccurate.

Logic: A question set is generated and show to the user. Each test has its own id using a particular question set. The responses chosen by the user are stored in the `test_response` table.

Comment: How and where u r setting the response_id (set only if all options marked are equal to the answer)for multiple choice questions...

Comment: Bcz I think the query is right but your way of updating the database for multiple choice questions are wrong...

Comment: @Abhinav i don't think you can check whether multiple rows for 1 question are correct without a group by or a window function..

Comment: @death: I am not checking after updating into database, I wanted to know whether OP is checking before inserting it into database that the user has all the marked answer as the correct answer.....

Comment: @Abhinav the test_response contains the response_id and the question_id for the answers that was chosen by the user. 

For Eg.  If there is a question "Which of the following names start with A ?" and choices are i) Anand ii) Ravi iii) Raj iv) Avi ... and the user selects Anand and Avi from the choices of the Response table.... then 2 rows will be created in the `test_response` table contating question_id of this question and the 2 question_response_id of Anand and Avi into response_id of `test_response` table.

Comment: you need 4 rows per 4-answer question, not 2 => if you can't change the desing, you need a table with correct answers to all questions to be joined to the query (to check for missing correct answers that would make the whole question incorrect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE: this does not work for OP's table design where 2 rows are created for 4-answer questions**

i think you need to first check each question if it has all answers correct and then count the questions without incorrect answers:

```
select
  count(*) - count(incorrect_answers_per_question) correct
from (
  select
    d.test_id,
    d.question_id,
    sum(case when r.correct_response_flag = 'N' then 1 end) incorrect_answers_per_question
  from test_response d
  join question_response r on d.response_id = r.question_resp_id
  where d.test_id = '10113'
  group by d.test_id, d.question_id
)
```

Comment: Ya, it worked. :) Thanks a lot... And instead of getting for a particular test If I want to get for all the tests... I will just remove _where d.test_id = '10113'_ and add _count(*) - count(incorrect_answers_per_question) correct, test_id_ right ?

Comment: yes - but this query doesn't check for missing correct answers if you don't insert into question_response that a correct answer is missing...